# Isolate for matrix X

Tags: matrices

So I have matrices A, B, X, C, D.

Isolate for matrix X.

$(A+B)XA^2+C=D$

I'm pretty stuck due to the squared part of this problem. Help appreciated!

Comment: What you have written doesn't make sense: if $A$ and $B$ are $n\times n$ and $X$ is $n\times 1$, then $(A+B)X$ is $n\times 1$... you cannot then multiply it on the right by $A^2$.

Comment: Well I don't know what X C and D are then. Can you answer the question if I remove that part?

Comment: The dimensions of the matrices are fairly important. Where did the question come from?

Comment: It's a homework assignment and the only additional information I get is that you assume that every matrix has an inverse.

Comment: They are probably square, then. You will also need that $A+B$ has an inverse, which does not follow from $A$ and $B$ being individually invertible. Why don't you list the steps you've tried and specifically where you get stuck?

Comment: This is what I've done so far:

$(A+B)XA^2+C=D$\\

$(A+B)XA^2=D-C$\\

$XA^2=(A+B)^{-1}(D-C)$\\

$X=A^{-2}(A+B)^{-1}(D-C)$\\

But I'm not sure whether this is the solution. I feel fairly lost with the squared part.

Comment: I can't even find anything on google about the inverse of squared matrices...How do I find the inverse of a matrix squared?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are on the right track, but you need to keep in mind that matrix multiplication *does not commute* and so you have to be very careful to go step by step.

First, as you did, subtract $C$ from both sides to get
$$(A+B)XA^2 = D-C.$$
Now you can multiply *on the left* by $(A+B)^{-1}$ to get
$$XA^2 = (A+B)^{-1}(D-C)$$
notice that this requires that $A+B$ be invertible, which is not necessarily true even if $A$ and $B$ are individually invertible.

Next, $A^2$ just means $AA$:
$$XAA = (A+B)^{-1}(D-C).$$
You can multiply *on the right* by $A^{-1}$ to get

$$XA = (A+B)^{-1}(D-C)A^{-1}$$
and do it again to get
$$X = (A+B)^{-1}(D-C)(A^{-1})^2$$
notic that you could have combined the previous two steps easily, but when in doubt, it never hurts to go step by step.

Comment: This solution resembles my own very much. Is $(A^{-1})^2$ not the same thing as $A^{-2}$ in this case then?

Comment: $(A^{-1})^2$ is indeed the same as $A^{-2}$. The difference is that your answer has $A^{-2}$ in the wrong place.

Comment: I see. So because it is to the far right on the left hand side, it must be as well on the right hand side?

Comment: You have to choose to multiply by $A^{-2}$ either on the left, or the right, on both sides. The only way to cancel the $A^2$ on the right is to multiply by $A^{-2}$ on the right.

Comment: I see, thank you for you help.